# How do you parse the sentence and what is "it"?

Tags: dummy-pronouns

> The bulk and weight of coal required in the majority of manufacturing
>   industries is large in comparison with the bulk and weight of other
>   raw materials. **This** is not always true -- as with the manufacture of
>   pig iron and steel from low-grade iron ores -- but **it** did lead to the
>   **concentration** of industrial developments on the coal-fields, a
>   phenomenon well seen in such countries as Britain where the Industrial
>   Revolution came before the days of oil or electricity. Coal being a
>   solid must be distributed mainly by rail or water.

I would think "**a phenomenon**" is the appositive of "**the concentration of industrial developments on the coal-fields**." Thus, "**it**" would refer to "**this**" in the previous sentence, which is the statement point in the first sentence. Does it make sense?

Comment: Both *this* and *it* have the entire first sentence as their referent. The issue of an appositive has no bearing on this—that's something that appears *after* the pronouns are used. (I also don't know why you used the `dummy-pronouns` tag. )

Comment: @JasonBassford, thanks for many thoughtful and helpful feedback on my questions. In this case, what part do you think the "a phenomenon ..." part modifies?

Comment: It modifies *the concentration of industrial developments on the coal-fields*, but my point is that it's not relevant to your question. You mention it and then say *thus*, making it appear as if you're saying that *it* refers to something ***because*** of the appositive. But that's not the case.

Comment: @JasonBassford, thanks, Jason. This is the way I understand the sentence: the "well seen ...by rail or water" part is just a past-participial adjective modifying "a phenomenon." thus, the entire "a phenomenon well seen...by rail or water.' part is just a noun phrase. I also agree "a phenomenon" modifies "the concentration of industrial developments on the coal-fields," and I've used the term appositive. But you think the term is kind of appropriate following a pronoun. If so, which terminology do you use to describe the modification relationship b/t "a phenomenon" and "the concentration..."?